# PHP function only digits

Tags: php, validation

I know of is_int and ctype_digit and others like that, but I need one that will return true ONLY AND ONLY IF ***ALL*** characters in value are numerical. ctype_digit will return true it you use scientific notation (5e4) so that will not work.

Has to return true if:

```
123
1.2
-12
```

if there is anything other than that above, will not work.

I'm stressing bout this because it seems like with all those built in functions ONE of them would be able to do this. Thanks alot guys!

Comment: Regular expression.  `/^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/`  Translation: Optional `-` at the beginning, 0 or more digits, optional `.`, more optional digits, end.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski can you be a little bit more descriptive? PS this validation is inside an IF statement (if it makes a difference)

Comment: Use it in `preg_match()`.  This has been asked before, so I'm searching for a comparable question with solid answers.

Comment: I did a google search. I understand it now. I cant vote your comment the best answer, but it was. Thank you!

Comment: @kylemorgan49: You should have researched that in the first place. And if I remember correctly, it has been asked on this website even long ago.

Comment: @hakre Let me know if you find anything to cv against. I'm not having much luck anything other than piles of `is_numeric()` answers...

Comment: Diverse answer outline also filter functions and preg_match. Also this question title isn't precise as well, "only digits" is not what is asked for. And I'm not so sure if OP want's to allow leading zeroes.

Comment: @hakre well I'm sorry I didn't sift through 3.9 million questions before asking. And I did search this for 1/2 hour.

Comment: I need it to support decimals, which it is not currnetly doing @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Oh and it's not working with negatives either.

Comment: @kylemorgan49 See my answer below please.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this ?

```
function is_numbers($value){
   if(is_float($value)) return true;
   if(is_int($value)) return true;
}
```

Comment: you need a `return false` statement at the end.

Comment: This will also not return true if the value is "42", since it's technically a string.

Comment: @doublesharp: No in the question it has only be said in which cases it has to return TRUE. The other cases are undefined (I'd say logically not TRUE, NULL is not TRUE)

Comment: @doublesharp: yes you are rite on `"42"` but if you have `42` it works. So may be he can strip quotes before passing it to the function.

Comment: If you are using that function expecting a boolean result, then you would return false for any condition that is not true. `(!true == false)`

Comment: @doublesharp: else part he can have anything.. I have just addressed the crux!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $tests = array("42",1337,"1e4","not numeric",array(),9.1);

      foreach ($tests as $element) 
      {
          if (is_numeric($element)) 
          {
             echo "'{$element}' is numeric", PHP_EOL;
          } 
          else 
          {
            echo "'{$element}' is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
          }

       }
    ?>
```

Comment: This test returns `'1e4' is numeric` which is not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I do stuff like this to check pure numbers

```
$var = (string) '123e4'; // number to test, cast to string if not already
$test1 = (int) $var; // will be int 123
$test2 = (string) $test1; // will be string '123'

if( $test2 === $var){
     // no letters in digits of integer original, this time will fail
   return true;
}
// try similar check for float by casting

 return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a suitable question with an answer that supports your needs exactly.  The regular expression I posted above will support both decimals and negatives. It also supports leading zeros, however. If you want to eliminate those it gets somewhat more complicated.

```
$pattern = '/^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/';

echo preg_match($pattern, '-1.234') ? "match" : "nomatch";
// match
echo preg_match($pattern, '-01.234') ? "match" : "nomatch";
// match
echo preg_match($pattern, '1234') ? "match" : "nomatch";
// match
echo preg_match($pattern, '001.234') ? "match" : "nomatch";
// match (leading zeros)
echo preg_match($pattern, '-1 234') ? "match" : "nomatch";
// nomatch (space)
echo preg_match($pattern, '-0') ? "match" : "nomatch";
// match (though this is weird)
echo preg_match($pattern, '1e4') ? "match" : "nomatch";
// nomatch (scientific)
```

Breaking down the pattern:

- `^` Start of the string
- `-?` an optional minus immediately at the start of the string
- `[0-9]*` Followed by zero or more digits
- `\.?` Followed by an optional decimal
- `[0-9]*` And optionally digits after the decimal
- `$` end of the string